# How to implement following multiple inner join in hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I hava query:

```
     Hibernate: select this_.pName as y0_, this_.kNum as y1_, count(*) as y2_ from ALL_CPView this_ inner join ALL_AMView aID1_ on this_.agentid=aID1_.AgentID
```

and criteria,

```
      Criteria crit = statelessSession.createCriteria(APRecord.class, "apr")
                .createAlias("manageID", "ID", Criteria.INNER_JOIN);
     crit.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("PName"), "PName")
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("kNum"), "kNum")
                .add(Projections.rowCount() , "count"));
        results =  crit.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(APStat.class)).list();
```

How can I add another projection with distinct count for aID with the inner join?